# How to change format of date and insert it in database using php and html only

Tags: php, html, mysql, date

I used this tag in html for accepting the date

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_POST["date"]));
```

I used this code for converting the date. The date is converted successfully if I simply echo it but date is not getting inserted in database. It gets posted as 00-00-0000 but if click it in database then proper date appears.The type 'date' is used in database to store the date.

Please tell me how to store it in database in that converted format.

Comment: MySQL uses `Y-m-d` format for dates, because it isn't ambiguous: `$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST["date"]));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help but I found the solution. We can simply enter the date by accepting input type='text' through HTML and store it directly in database and we can use this code while displaying data from database :-

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_POST["date"]));
```

Now we can see data in dd-mm-yy format now this works perfectly...

Answer (score 1):

You can't store it in the database in that format in a date field. The database stores dates in Y-m-d format (YYYY-MM-DD), when you read the date out again and display it, then convert it to the format you want it to show as.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your table has a date with a `date` or `datetime` datatype.
Make sure that you store it in the 'Y-m-d' format.
The you could `select` it from the table:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(my_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS my_date FROM table;
```

Then echo the "my_date" entry; it should come out right.
If you wanted to select it in the d-m-Y format,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(my_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS my_date FROM table;
```